# Multicast observable: attempting to subscribe results in "cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined" error

Tags: ecmascript-6, rxjs, rxjs5

I have a need in my code to perform an AJAX request and send the resulting data to two different places, so I figured using a multicast observable was the easiest way of achieving this.  My code looks like this:

In the constructor for my 'app' object:

```
this.getEpisodeDescription = (id) => jsonLoader("http://www.randomtext.me/api/lorem/p-2/8-24", "text_out");

function jsonLoader (url, field)
{
    let stream = Rx.Observable.ajax ({ url: url, crossDomain: true })
                                .retry (1)
                                .pluck ("response");
    if (field !== undefined)
        return stream.pluck(field);
    else
        return stream;
}
```

I've successfully used this method before to retrieve data for a single receiver, so I'm sure this is working OK.  The caller is new, however:

```
loadSummary (id)
{
    let cachedValue = this.summaries.get(id);
    if (cachedValue !== undefined) return Rx.Observable.of(cachedValue);

    let observable = this.app.getEpisodeDescription(id);
    let multicast = observable.multicast ().refCount ();
    multicast.subscribe(result => this.summaries.put(id, result));
    return multicast;
}
```

When I try executing this method, I get the following stack trace:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at Observable.ConnectableObservable._subscribe (app.js:44193)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (app.js:10253)
    at Observable.subscribe (app.js:10241)
    at RefCountOperator.call (app.js:44275)
    at Observable.subscribe (app.js:10238)
    at AsyncAction.SubscribeOnObservable.dispatch (app.js:71532)
    at AsyncAction._execute (app.js:21083)
    at AsyncAction.execute (app.js:21058)
    at AsyncScheduler.flush (app.js:21156)
```

(Ignore file name and line numbers -- I'm using webpack and it doesn't seem to be producing a working line number map at the moment)

Any ideas what's going on?  Specifically, how does it happen that I get an object out of the call to `multicast` that has appropriate `subscribe` etc methods, but when you try to subscribe to it it apparently can't subscribe to the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter to the `multicast()` operator is either Subject factory function or a Subject instance.

This means you should be using it like this if you want to have one shared Subject instance:

```
let multicast = observable.multicast(new Subject()).refCount();
```

... or like this to make a new Subject for every observer:

```
let multicast = observable.multicast(() => new Subject()).refCount();
```